# Regex conditional

Tags: regular-expression, perl

In my code file I have several lines as`T V= X T(A);` And I want the text after `=` to be replaced as `X(T,A)` with some help I got this pattern   `s/X\s+([^\(]*)\(/X(\1,/g;` for find and replace it works great but the problem is when we have no args to pass for `T`  Ex.`T V= X T();` then after replacement it will be like `X(T,)` (see the extra comma) I knew it's because of `/X(\1,` can somebody help me rid of that extra comma, Sadly I am no regex guy.

Is there any sort of conditional we could have to say if the `()` is empty then do `X(\1/g` rather than `/X(\1,/g`

Comment: Use two `s`: `sed -E 's/X\s+([^\(]*)\(\)/X(\1)/g;s/X\s+([^\(]*)\(/X(\1,/g'` the 1st one will only replace the `T()` stuff, the 2nd one will replace the rest (as the `T()` was already changed and no longer matches the regex)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to do it, if you run it on the file(s) *after* having run the first substitution that introduces the error:

```
sed 's/X(\([^,]*\),)/X(\1)/g'
```

It will substitute `X(<something-not-a-comma>,)` with `X(<something-not-a-comma>)`.

To do both substitutions in one go:

```
sed -e 'the first substitution' -e 'the second substitution'
```

Comment: it works for sure ,but I really wanna avoid second run

Comment: @FallingFromBed you know you can run both substitution in one pass ?

Comment: @FallingFromBed Updated. I thought that you now had files with the error in them.

Comment: sed -e s/X\s+([^\(]*)\(/X(\1,/g -e 's/X(\([^,]*\),\)/X(\1)/g' error -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @FallingFromBed You need to single-quote the first expression too.

Comment: is it right `sed -e 's/X\s+([^\(]*)\(/X(\1,/g' -e 's/X(\([^,]*\),)/X(\1)/g' ./file`?

Comment: @FallingFromBed That looks correct to me.

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 28: Unmatched ( or \(

Comment: @don_crissti That will make the second substitution wrong though.

Comment: @don_crissti I can't see any `-E` when i do `sed --help`

Answer (score 1):

@Kusalananda Looks like he is using Extended regex without -E option in his first substitution command in

```
sed -e 's/X\s+([^\(]*)\(/X(\1,/g' -e 's/X(\([^,]*\),)/X(\1)/g' ./file
```

But the second command looks fine.
Making everything in extended Regex, this will work

```
sed -Ee 's/X\s+([^\(]*)\(/X(\1,/g;s/X\(([^,]*),\)/X(\1)/g' ./file
```

Comment: @FallingFromBed See this for your query about -E option 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139126/whats-the-difference-between-sed-e-and-sed-e

Comment: No, I'm not using ERE in my substitution.

Comment: Of course,You didn't. So i changed your command into Extended regex form as well. Verify if its correct.

Comment: what the `-r` is for?

Comment: does `sed -Ee 's/X\s+([^\(]*)\(/X(\1,/g' -Ee 's/X\(([^,]*),\)/X(\1)/g'` works?

Comment: Just another option for enabling Extended Regex. Basically, -E and -r does the same.

Comment: @FallingFromBed It's the same as `-E`, but in GNU `sed`.

Comment: Anyway this answer showing me the help text when i execute did you try?

Comment: Try this, this is working.
    
    sed -Ee 's/X\s+([^\(]*)\(/X(\1,/g;s/X\(([^,]*),\)/X(\1)/g'
    
Updated the answer as well

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Input : `echo 'T V= X T() T V= X T(A)' | sed -Ee 's/X\s+([^\(]*)\(/X(\1,/g;s/X\(([^,]*),\)/X(\1)/g'`
Output : `T V= X(T) T V= X(T,A)` .
Now tell me what problem are you facing?